# Перегрузка оператора < c++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, почему не работает перегрузка оператора < ?

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;  

class Date  
{  
    int kurs; 
    float rate, avarage;  
public:  
    Date(int m, float d, float y)  
    {  
        kurs = m; rate = d; avarage = y;  
    }  
    bool operator < (Date &v1)
    {
        int vTemp1 = v1.kurs;

        return vTemp1;
    }
    ~Date(){}
};  



int main()  
{  
    Date dt(35, 116, 92);
    Date dt1(70, 69, 92);
    bool k = dt1<dt;  
    if(k) cout << "dt < dt1";
    else cout << "dt > dt1";
    getch(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ну так у вас он написан так, что что бы вы ни сравнивали, выведется `kurs` того, что справа от сравнения, приведенный к `bool` - т.е. `true`...

Если вы хотите, скажем, сравнивать по полю `kurs`, то напишите

```
bool operator < (const Date &v1) const
{
    return kurs < v1.kurs;
}
```